# Lombok @Builder not working in lombok-1.16.18 java:cannot find symbol builderclass

Tags: java, lombok

```
@Builder
public class ProcessorLombokBO {
    private String panel;
    private String motherBoard;
    private String ram;
    private String hardDisk;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ProcessorLombokBO processorLombokBO =
                    new ProcessorLombokBO.ProcessorLombokBOBuilder()
                    .panel("Brown")
                    .hardDisk("SanDisk 256GB")
                    .ram("4GB")
                    .motherBoard("Intel")
                    .build();
    System.out.println(processorLombokBO);
}
```

I am trying to implemenent `@Builder` in a POJO, but it gives the below error when I execute the `main` method.

> java: cannot find symbol
>   symbol: class ProcessorLombokBOBuilder

Did I miss something?

Comment: Where is the error, in your IDE? If so then are you sure your IDE is compatible with Lombok and you have required plugins/extensions?

Comment: Lombok-plugin for IDE installed?

Comment: ya.. Using Intellij.. Other examples are working fine with lombok

Comment: I had the same problem. Added lombok to the project (plugin was installed before), all lombok-related stuff worked instead of `builder`, which was not visible. After restart Android studio the issue disappeared

Answer (score 8):

I had this same issue and found that @Builder support was disabled in IntelliJ:

[image: Intellij 2018.3 Lombok Plugin Settings]

Comment: can you please tell where to find this setting, i can't find it in mine. Thank you

Comment: It was at: Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> Lombok plugin for me. 

FYI: I was able to quickly find this using the search feature in Preferences.

Comment: @DoctorParameter I can't find this setting - For Lombok, I only see "Enable lombok version warning" checkbox and nothing else.

Comment: I'm on IntelliJ v2020.2 and Lombok plugin 0.33-2020.2. Maybe the setting is gone or you need to update?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `mapstruct-processor` plugin in your Maven project, it will affect the `builder` method.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Exactly my problem, thanks for the idea.

Comment: Is that a solution ? I already have this `annotationProcessorPaths` element in the plugin and I'm still facing the OP issue.

Comment: Yes it is, for some reason, if you don't add this plugin, it would cause failure.
Have you tried copying what my solution to your Maven? Maybe you forgot something somewhere. @Stephane

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** Try making your inner ProcessorLombokBO class static.
You can't use Builder on an inner non-static class, as the compile error at your example suggests in my IDE (Eclipse)

> The method builder cannot be declared static; static methods can only
>   be declared in a static or top level type

The reason is that `@Builder`generates an inner static class (the ProcessorLombokBOBuilder class) and adds a static method `builder()`, which is  by specification only possible if the outer class is also static, because else you need an enclosing instance to reference the Builder class, which contradicts the concept of a static type.

**Original Post:** Usually you instanciate your Builder via

```
ProcessorLombokBO.builder()
```

Comment: I have tried the same. I am getting this error java: cannot find symbol symbol: method builder()

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The same code was working in eclipse. Things are not working only in Intellij. I dont know why.

Comment: Can you post a complete example of your code? Is ProcessorLombokBO in a dedicated java file or is it an inner class in the same class as your main() function?

Comment: I have the same problem in 1.16.18 - the `builder()` method was not visible anywhere in the code. I've downgraded Lombok to 1.16.16 and `builder()`  works as intended. What's strange is that after I've upgraded to 1.16.18 again, everything works - maybe its an Issue with some caching in Intellij?

Comment: That's odd. Maybe you just forgot to restart your ide after installing the plugin the first time? That's what happened to me once :-) Else, if you can reproduce that behaviour it could be interesting to the folks at [the Lombok github page](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues)

Comment: As @mcmil proposed, I've just rebuild my pom.xml and everything back to normal.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the following entry to your POM, it helped in my case:

```
                       <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>0.2.0</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
```

Comment: I also had to have the lombok dependency.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, following up on the solution provided by @markkush to whom credits should go, I could work around the same issue as the one posted by the OP. I also had to have the `lombok` Maven dependency and the following entries in the compiler plugin:

```
  <properties>
    <lombok.version>1.18.26</lombok.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>${lombok.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>
              <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
              <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            </exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>17</source>
          <target>17</target>
          <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
              <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
              <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
              <version>1.5.5.Final</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
              <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
              <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
              <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
              <version>0.2.0</version>
            </path>
          </annotationProcessorPaths>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```